What is the negative condition of willing in System of Transcendental idealism?
In System of Transcendental idealism P160, Schelling said the negative condition lies outside the intelligence.

Hence the act has to be explicable from something that both
is and is not a producing on the part of the intelligence.
This contradiction can be mediated in no other way save the following: This something which contains the ground of free self-determination must be a producing on the part of the intelligence, although
the negative condition of this producing must lie outside it; the former,
because nothing enters the intelligence save through its own action;
the latter, because in and for itself this act is not to be explicable from
the intelligence itself. Conversely, the negative condition of this something outside the intelligence must be a determination in the intelligence itself, doubtless a negative one; and since the intelligence is but
an act, it will have to be a nonaction of the intelligence.

But then he said that the intelligence contains the negative condition.

The intelligence is thus to intuit an action as resulting, and as with all other intuiting by means of a producing in the intelligence, there must therefore be no immediate influence exerted upon the latter, there must be no positive condition of its intuiting lying outside it, it must remain as
always entirely closed up within itself; and likewise, on the other
hand, it must not be the cause of this action, but must merely contain
the negative condition thereof, and to that extent the action has to
take place in complete independence of the intelligence.

This really confuses me. I don't understand what the negative condition is and why it can lie both outside
and within the intelligence.

Schelling uses language very similar to Fichte here, but I'm not sure if he is using the terms in the same way. The negative condition for Fichte is the absence of freedom (the feeling of necessity), which we later attribute to objects and other persons (but for Fichte, ultimately arise from the intelligence itself). It is negative in that it limits the original motion of the intelligence which is accompanied by a feeling of freedom.
